# '&' used with non-inout argument of type 'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<UIImage?>'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pointers, uiimage

My new interface needs to call an old (Objective-C) rendering function. First I tried this:

```
func renderImage(image:UIImage) {
    var imageCopy = UIImage(CGImage: image.CGImage!)
    Renderer.imageWithSourceImg(&imageCopy, ...)
}
```

And I'm getting an error:

```
'&' used with non-inout argument of type 'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<UIImage?>'
```

I've read about how to call a function with a pointer, you need to have a `var` binding instead of `let`, which is why I guessed with the `imageCopy` thing.

Basically I have an immutable image that gets passed in as an argument, and I need to call a function that takes a mutable image pointer as an argument. How?

UPDATE: Objective-c interface:

```
+(UIImage *)imageWithSourceImg:(UIImage **)_sourceImgPtr
    ...
```

Comment: Note that I've also tried creating a brand new unrelated image. I can't get that to work either.

Comment: Please show the Objective-C API. Can't tell you how to call the Objective-C function if we don't know how Objective-C declares the function.

Comment: Try making the variable 'imageCopy' have type 'UIImage?'.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the following Objective-C API for Renderer:

```
+(UIImage *)imageWithSourceImg:(UIImage **)_sourceImgPtr;
```

The generated interface in Swift is:

```
class func imageWithSourceImg(
    _sourceImgPtr: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<UIImage?>
) -> UIImage!
```

You need to take that `<UIImage?>` generic specifier seriously. This, then, compiles fine for me:

```
var im : UIImage? = UIImage() // note the type
let im2 = Renderer.imageWithSourceImg(&im)
```

The result, `im2`, will be typed as `UIImage!`, which means you should probably check for a `nil` result before you try to use it.